# Clone VirtualBox Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have Oracle VM VirtualBox running on Centos5.8.

I currently have two machines on it; one with Windows XP and IE6 and a second with Windows XP IE7.

I now wish to create a third running Windows XP IE8.

Instead of creating a new machine and reinstalling windows, is it possible to clone or copy one of the existing machines?

Comment: Machine/Clone is shown on the menu, but is grayed out.

Comment: Is there a status of limitation for down voting bad questions?  This one happened almost 6 years after I posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I am not completely familiar with VirtualBox, (I use VMware Player), but the concept is still the same. The easiest way to clone a virtual machine is to shut the vm down. Find where the file for that machine is (usually a .vmdk) and copy and paste it. You can then tell VirutalBox to open that copy.

The clone feature provided by VirtualBox is to provide a hot-clone, or clone the machine while it is running. Most products charge for this feature, but still allow a user to create a cold-copy with the machine off, using the procedure described above.

---

-or-

If that doesn't work, you can just copy the .vdi file(the hard drive) and attach it to a new VM as the primary HDD. I found this post in a forum.

"I've had success with copying the .vdi harddisk image with the command VBoxManage clonevdi ImageYouWantToCopy.vdi DestinationImage.vdi. Then just make a new VM that uses the new .vdi. It's a bit cumbersome, but it seems to work fine."

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=674

Comment: Thanks Scott,  Searching as we speak where the file is.

Comment: Turns out you can use the GUI if you first stop the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do clone a VirtualBox Machine with all its snapshots. It's better to do it from the command-line, as it becomes very repeatable and you can use it over and over again.

From the command-line type:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe clonevm old_VM_name --mode all new_VM_name --basefolder "C:\Users\username\VirtualBox VMs" --register
```

Heres the explanation

`--mode all`: states that all snapshots and folders should be copied.

`--basefolder "C:\Users\username\VirtualBox VMs"` : mentions where the VM folder should be located

`--register`: registers the VM so that you can use it immediately after the cloning process from the VirtualBox GUI or CLI